# Assign two tables join result to List in c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'd like to return two tables result to list .

```
public List<dynamic> GetStatistics(DateTime startDate , DateTime endDate)
{
    try
    {
        List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();

        using (XactETLEntities xactCtxt = new XactETLEntities())
        {
            var query = (from a in xactCtxt.XactETL_Activity_Log
                     join b in xactCtxt.XactETL_Shred_Mode on a.ShredModeID 
                                                         equals b.ShredModeID
                    where a.CreatedDate >= startDate && a.CreatedDate <= endDate
                    select new { a, b });

            result = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I am not able to assign result to query.ToList()

Comment: `List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();` this is only accessible inside the GetStatistics method so even if it did return valid data you would not be able to view it outside the scope of the existing method.. have you considered `debugging` this to see where the breakdown is happening before asking others for an immediate answer to your existing problem and or issue also I would recommend doing a google search on the following `new List<dynamic>()`

Comment: What is the best way return the data from query variable to bind it to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is query is not an IEnumerable so the ToList() function is not returning the correct list type. Also, anonymous types can not be cast to anything but object, and are internal. Your best bet is trying to make your select more explicit.

Instead of:

```
select new { a, b });
```

you could use:

```
select (dynamic)new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(a, b)
```

this will result in your query returning an IEnumerable of dynamic, where each item is actually a tuple underneath.

**EDIT:**
The solution was to have the query cast all the items as objects, before converting to a list.

```
query.Select(o => (object)o).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any simpler way?

Comment: You could use objects instead. `select (object) new { a, b}` and then have your function return a `List<object>`

Comment: I am getting this error  Error 1 A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type          if I try with List<object>

Comment: ah. then that casting doesn't work. How about `query.Select(o => (object)o).ToList();`